# Connection string in .NET app to MsSQL under docker on MacOS

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker

I am working on MacOS and ran MsSQL under docker.
The connection string in appsettings.js is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=InAndOut;Integrated Security=True;User ID=sa;Password=reallyStrongPwd123;"
  },
```

I successfully executed update-database in the PM console. But the site fails:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
> ...

The google says it is usually a connection string issue. Could you help me please to figure put what is wrong. I am an absolutely newbie in .NET

Here is the connection in DBeaver:
[image: connection]

Comment: db is persistent storage, and better not be in docker(localhost indicates that).

Comment: @LeiYang why? There's no problem with using any database in Docker. It's the easiest way to install a database, and all vendors have published Docker images. In production you'd have to configure the container to store the *database files* outside the container, but working on a laptop is certainly not "production"

Comment: @NikitaGolbeg I'm using SQL Server on Docker on a Mac. You don't need to modify the connection string *at all*, as long as you map the internal port to an external port. This goes for *every* application that runs inside Docker. The server running inside Docker listens on a port that isn't exposed outside the container. You need to map that internal port to an external one when you create the container

Comment: Follow the instructions in [Quickstart: Run SQL Server container images with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash). You need to map the ports when you call `docker run` with `-p 1433:1433`

Comment: The connection string is invalid. `ArgumentNullException` isn't thrown by ADO.NET though, there's a different bug in the application code. Post the **full** exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. This will show where the exception was thrown and which calls led to it. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Docker or even SQL Server. Perhaps some data access method tries to read from the database, fails and hides the error, eg with a `catch{}` and ends up returning a `null` that's passed to another method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you were right. The connection string is correct, the issue was in the code, no model was passed to the view. Thanks, the problem solved.

Comment: @NikitaGolberg the connection string in the question isn't correct. `Integrated Security=True;` means Windows\AD Authentication while `User ID=sa;Password=reallyStrongPwd123;` uses SQL authentication. You [can use AD authentication even on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15) through Kerberos, so even on Linux you can't use both options in the same connection string. I suspect this is not the *actual* connection string used. DBeaver uses only SQL authentication

Comment: @NikitaGolberg as the linked tutorial shows, AD authentication on Linux is messy to set up but once done, you no longer need to bother about passwords

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is correct. The issue was in the code.

Comment: This isn't a good Answer. You should explain what was wrong about the code. Yes, you mentioned it in a comment but it needs to be in the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception on MacOs.
My problem was that in connection string I was using server name instead of port.

Incorrect format:

`Server=10.10.10.51\\DEV1;`

Correct format:

`Server=10.10.10.51,1434;`

The default port of SQL Server is 1433.